# How to exract placeholder sub strings from a string in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, placeholder

I have this string `"this ${is} a sample ${text}"`
I want a list of all sub-strings which are wrapped with ${}

I tried this and it worked

```
re.findall("{(.*?)}", "this ${is} a sample ${text}")
['is', 'text']

However, I would like to narrow down the search by using the $ symbol too. 
The following command return []
re.findall("${(.*?)}", "this ${is} a sample ${text}")


re.findall("${(.*?)}", "this ${is} a sample ${text}")

The expected output should be ['is', 'text']
```

Comment: escape the symbol use `re.findall("\${(.*?)}", "this ${is} a sample ${text}")`

Comment: It worked by escaping \. Thanks.